# What diagnostic tool do I need for my car?

Tags: electrical

Car is a civic coupe vti 1999.

The check engine light has come on.

There is no obd port on this car as obd cane in use after 2000 I believe.

So what device do I need and what is the name of the port that I need to search for since it’s not an obd port.

Comment: You need to double check ... OBDII came around in 1996. If you can't find the port, I'd suggest you haven't looked hard enough. IIRC, on these Civics, they are up under the dash by the driver's side kick panel (that's where it's at in the States ... might be slightly different for RHD vehicles). My point is, you might have to dig a little bit to find it.

Comment: Some older honda's have the obd port under the astray and a rubber flap  in front the gear selector.